# regular expression crashing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a regular expression validating urls

```
/(^$|^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$)/
```

Whilst I know that this is not correct in the sense it does not allow for the hash symbol for example, rather than throwing up a validation error, it is just crashing the app. It also seemed to crash an independant regex tester.

The URL used for testing was http://www.wmagazine.com/celebrities/2012/10/jennifer-lawrence-actress-katniss-everdeen-hunger-games-cover-story-ss#slide=1

Can anyone shed light as to why?

code context is this is used within a model validating a URL that is entered by the user to be rendered onto a page

```
validates :source_link, :format => { :with => /(^$|^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$)/,
                                   :message => 'Only valid urls allowed' }, :if => :apply_validations?
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful, you need to show the context the regex is used in, otherwise we can't help you. There are many ways to crash an application, a single regex string sin't really one of them.

Comment: See my edit, I have added context

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar enough with the methods you are using to provide a useful answer, but being responsive and improving your question receives my vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that crashes the thing is here:

```
/(^$|^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$)/
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are nesting quantifiers and the regex has here too many possibilities to find a valid match. This is called [**Catastrophic Backtracking**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

This matches exactly the same strings:

```
/(^$|^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)\/?$)/
```

and will fail much quicker, when it does not match.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[\da-z\.-]+)\.(?:[a-z\.]{2,6})(?:[\/\w \.#=-]*)\/?$
```

Although I highly doubt that this is "good" to match URL's, I suggest to take a look at other answers.

**Online [demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/qV3bG2), [demo 2](http://rubular.com/r/lBQa47jKt1).**